# Blurred textblocks when used in animations

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am simulating the semantic zoom effect in a Windows Store app using animations between two canvas'. However when I "zoom out" the `TextBlock` that appear on the canvas, appear as VERY blurry until the animation completes.

This only happens for the first animation, after that the text is clear on all subsequent animations.

I suspecting a bitmap caching type issue but either setting the `CacheMode` to Bitmap or null makes no difference.

Are there any settings that can control or change this?

[image: compare of page during and post zoom]

The XAML used for the animation is fairly straight forward, toggle visibility and then uses a simple DoubleAnimation to change the scale of the X & Y values of the `Grid` which contain the various images. Inside each `Grid` is a `ViewBox` and inside that is a custom control (not a `TemplatedControl` - just a plain old custom one).

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition From="ZoomedIn" GeneratedDuration="0" To="ZoomedOut">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.01"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.01"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualTransition>
            <VisualTransition From="ZoomedOut" GeneratedDuration="0" To="ZoomedIn">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.01"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.01"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="ZoomedIn"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="ZoomedOut">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedOutGrid">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomedInGrid">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I have recreated a similar issue in a much simpler scenario, the code can be obtained from [GitHub](https://github.com/rmaclean/BlurryAnimationIssue) and to see the issue there here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTgMGpLX4l0&feature=youtu.be), note the blurry text when we go from zoomed out back to normal state.

Similar issues:

- Same problem with `TextBlocks` however the fixes of placing inside
  canvas and/or rectangle, do not help:
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ddd9f28e-f682-4070-9a48-5b584689df0c
- Similar issue however it seems to affect a `Border` element:
  [WinRT (C#/XAML) Scale without blurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870246/winrt-c-xaml-scale-without-blurring)
- Similar issue but not solutions in it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/73ff7a75-58bf-4e01-807d-7aeb32918333
- Similar issue http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/78d5b388-45ba-4131-9ca8-061f183d7774

Comment: Using DoubleAnimation? Maybe share your animation xaml to recreate? Or maybe how you're "simulating semantic zoom" to see if it might make more sense for an alternative like for instance just utilizing the benefits of `ViewBox` instead of transitioning between Canvas's etc.

Comment: @ChrisW. added more information on the animation and the code for it.

Comment: So, I'm thinking I may not be getting the overall picture here. Even if your art is bitmaps as opposed to vector paths, what's the need for the separate `ZoomedInGrid`/`ZoomedOutGrid` if you're still using `ViewBox` and I'm not seeing how exactly just the `TextBlock` `UIElement` is taking on the blur from the X/Y Scaling and nothing else? On top of that, it looks like the TextBlock's have dimension bounds causing those blurry boxes for each instead of just blurs. Hate to ask but perhaps a bit more needs added to this picture?

Comment: @ChrisW. I have replicated the issue in a simpler project & linked the question to the GitHub repo for the issue. In addition there is also a YouTube video of the simpler issue.

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT - I agree, but I do not believe your's is the correct answer. It is surely a valid answer but not correct for the problem.

Comment: I understand, but your question is "Are there any settings that can control or change this?" You do have an answer to your question. I can't rewrite Windows for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Text is not full rendered during animations/zooms. Once complete, the comprehensive rendering is invoked. This is common on almost every platform. If this is killing you, you can animate an image (which is basically what Direct3D is doing). Make sense? I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old issue. But just in case it helps someone:

I found that scaling X and Y by different amounts causes the blurry text.

**Example: Try to scale X (from *0.3* to 1) while scaling Y (from *0* to 1)** -That causes blur.

My suggestion would be try to keep the same aspect ratio during your scaling.

**Example: if X scale (from 0 to 1), then Y scale (from 0 to 1)** - In my case, no blur issue