# UWP Cleartype or smooth font?

Tags: uwp

Is it just me or does UWP text look kind of jagged? Is there any way to fix this? For example the text on my buttons doesnt look so nice. Is there a high quality mode or anything for text which I can activate?

Comment: You should probably try a different size or different font.

Comment: @IvanIčin in fact im using the default font whatever that might be.

Comment: @IvanIčin Have you encountered anything similar?

Comment: I agree with @IvanIčin, you should increase the font size and set the font weight to at least `Semibold` for buttons.

Comment: You may always create text as bitmap with smooth anti-aliasing like here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346561/how-to-animate-scale-of-textblock-in-uwp

Comment: @JustinXL yep but it still seems as if they changed the rendering engine or something. In WPF the font is like 3 times nicer.

Comment: @JetChopper but why did they change this? They are basically destroying readability for performance.

Comment: @JetChopper what about situations where I have entire textfields? I would have to create a bitmap out of it.

Comment: I think it's due to performance. Don't know :)

Comment: @JetChopper oh boy, UWP is seriously crippled xD

Comment: @Asperger this is not a forum, you ask technical questions get technical answers, not on why something is implemented like something, as such questions can't be answered. But since you have asked, the reason is probably that the platform is not optimized for the old technology. Get yourself some decent display and it will work as it should.

Comment: @IvanIčin old but no alternative. So they could have sticked to it until they got something better.

Comment: @JetChopper you gave me a good idea. Check out my answer : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cleartype you would have to use Win2D then write the following code in your draw handler:

```
public void Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs e) {
    e.DrawingSession.TextAntialiasing = CanvasTextAntialiasing.ClearType;
    e.DrawingSession.Clear(Colors.White);
    e.DrawingSession.DrawText("Hello", 50, 50, 400, 400, Colors.Black, new CanvasTextFormat());
}
```

In your XAML import:

```
xmlns:Canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
```

And add the following canvas element:

```
<Canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="ClearTypeSample" Draw="Draw"/>
```

The rendering is extremely fast so you dont have to worry about it. The result should be smooth and sharp just as in WPF.