# Scaling a Path in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm porting my wpf application to a windows store app. I‘m drawing a path on a Canvas and as the user zooms in on the Canvas, the path's StrokeThickness is reduced accordingly to keep the same visual thickness. This works well in my wpf application and also in a Windows Phone 8 App but when I do this in my Store App, the line pixelates as shown on this picture: http://s21.postimg.org/6g0u6fd7r/Path_Scaling.png

Zoom Level 1

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Path Stroke="Red" Data="M0,0 L100,100" StrokeThickness="40"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Zoom Level 500

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="500" ScaleY="500"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Path Stroke="Red" Data="M0,0 L100,100" StrokeThickness="0.08"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Can someone please point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: Might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870246/winrt-c-xaml-scale-without-blurring & http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9a62ce20-af0f-4def-b5c4-db5b82566ec0/blurry-lines-in-xaml-winrt