# Windows Phone 8.1: Animation using Storyboard

Tags: animation, windows-runtime, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1, scaletransform

I am developing an application for windows phone 8.1 runtime i.e. store application. here I am applying *Storyboard* animation to *stackpanel*,

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="StkPnl">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="StkPnl">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Here I am scaling it like:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
```

Means from 0.2 to 1 and not from 0 to 1.

**My question is:** If I Scale object(here stackpanel) from 0.2 to 1 it looks like **blurred** till animation finishes. If I do it from 0 to 1 then it works great.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StkPnlName" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,512,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Height="38" Width="38" Fill="Blue"/>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xcode" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource Resource}"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Text" Foreground="Black" MaxHeight="38" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center" Width="74" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource Resource}" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
</StackPanel>
```

What I am missing? Anyone came across this situation please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't to know what blurred mean in your case but the animation works fine for me, can you provide screenshot, also can you provide the stackpanel xaml part .

Comment: See Update 1...Blur effect comes only when I am using EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value>0 for first and 1 for second.

Comment: The blur effect not comes in my case because I called the animation when I clicked a button. If you call the animation on "OnNavigatedTo" it comes. It's seems like a bug, there is a discussion in another stackoverflow question about this problem and Filip Skakun found trick  to fix it, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870246/winrt-c-xaml-scale-without-blurring

Comment: I have done on both OnNaigatedTo and button click same effect on both sides... are you using start value which is greater then 0.(here 0.2)

Comment: Yes, sure. that's why I get the blur effect when I called the animation on OnNavigatedTo .

Comment: I am getting blur effect if I have done this on only button click.